# Discord.js v12 clear command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a `clear` command which deletes the amount of messages you would like to. But whenever I say `clear 3`, it'll clear only 2 messages instead.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (
    message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'clear') ||
    message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'c ')
  ) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
      return message.channel.send("You cant use this command since you're missing `manage_messages` perm");
    if (!isNaN(message.content.split(' ')[1])) {
      let amount = 0;
      if (message.content.split(' ')[1] === '1' || message.content.split(' ')[1] === '0') {
        amount = 1;
      } else {
        amount = message.content.split(' ')[1];
        if (amount > 100) {
          amount = 100;
        }
      }
      await message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).then((_message) => {
        message.channel.send(`Bot cleared \`${_message.size}\` messages :broom:`).then((sent) => {
          setTimeout(function () {
            sent.delete();
          }, 2500);
        });
      });
    } else {
      message.channel.send('enter the amount of messages that you would like to clear').then((sent) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
          sent.delete();
        }, 2500);
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'help clear') {
      const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('#00B2B2').setTitle('**Clear Help**');
      newEmbed
        .setDescription('This command clears messages for example `.clear 5` or `.c 5`.')
        .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp();
      message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works fine, it deletes the correct number of messages. What you forgot is that your current message with the comment is also a message, and will also count towards the amount deleted. So you can increase this number by one.

I would probably make some changes to your code:

1. Instead of splitting your message by a single space, I'd use a regex to catch more than one spaces. The current one wouldn't work with `.clear  5`. If you check, `isNaN(' ')` is `false`.
2. Check if the amount is positive.
3. Remove hardcoded `prefix`es.
4. Remove unnecessary `await`.
5. Add an early check for the `prefix`.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content
    .toLowerCase()
    .slice(prefix.length)
    .trim()
    .split(/\s+/);
  const [command, input] = args;

  if (command === 'clear' || command === 'c') {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
      return message.channel
        .send(
          "You cant use this command since you're missing `manage_messages` perm",
        );
    }

    if (isNaN(input)) {
      return message.channel
        .send('enter the amount of messages that you would like to clear')
        .then((sent) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            sent.delete();
          }, 2500);
        });
    }

    if (Number(input) < 0) {
      return message.channel
        .send('enter a positive number')
        .then((sent) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            sent.delete();
          }, 2500);
        });
    }

    // add an extra to delete the current message too
    const amount = Number(input) > 100
      ? 101
      : Number(input) + 1;

    message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true)
    .then((_message) => {
      message.channel
        // do you want to include the current message here?
        // if not it should be ${_message.size - 1}
        .send(`Bot cleared \`${_message.size}\` messages :broom:`)
        .then((sent) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            sent.delete();
          }, 2500);
        });
    });
  }

  if (command === 'help' && input === 'clear') {
    const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#00B2B2')
      .setTitle('**Clear Help**')
      .setDescription(
        `This command clears messages for example \`${prefix}clear 5\` or \`${prefix}c 5\`.`,
      )
      .setFooter(
        `Requested by ${message.author.tag}`,
        message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
      )
      .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send(newEmbed);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's deleting the message triggering it too. Simple fix, just take the number given, and add one to it.

```js
await message.channel.bulkDelete(parseInt(amount) + 1, true).then((_message) => {
```

Comment: It sounds good, but in JavaScript if `amount` is a string, `amount + 1` will also be a string. I mean, if `amount = "3"`, `amount +1` will be `"31"`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros amount shouldn't be a string here though.

Comment: It is though. If `message.content` is `'.clear 3'` and you check the `typeof message.content.split(' ')[1]`, it returns `"string"`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Check my edit. I think that'll work?

Comment: Yep, that should work fine, although it's a good practice to add the radix too: `parseInt(amount, 10) + 1`. Let me upvote your answer now ;)

Answer (score 1):

The triggering message (command message) is also getting fetched.

There are multiple solutions:

1. Delete the command message before you fetch/bulk delete the other messages
2. Only fetch messages which got sent before the command message
3. Increment the amount of deleting messages by 1

I marked all 3 solutions in the following code

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (
    message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'clear') ||
    message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'c ')
  ) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
      return message.channel.send("You cant use this command since you're missing `manage_messages` perm");
    if (!isNaN(message.content.split(' ')[1])) {
      let amount = 0;
      if (message.content.split(' ')[1] === '1' || message.content.split(' ')[1] === '0') {
        amount = 1;
      } else {
        amount = message.content.split(' ')[1];
        if (amount > 100) {
          amount = 100;
        }
      }

/* 1. Solution */

      await message.delete().catch(e => { amount++; });

      await message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).then((_message) => {
        message.channel.send(`Bot cleared \`${_message.size}\` messages :broom:`).then((sent) => {
          setTimeout(function () {
            sent.delete();
          }, 2500);
        });
      });

/* 2. Solution */
      const messagesToDelete = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ before: message.id, limit: amount });

      await message.channel.bulkDelete(messagesToDelete, true).then((_message) => {
        message.channel.send(`Bot cleared \`${_message.size}\` messages :broom:`).then((sent) => {
          setTimeout(function () {
            sent.delete();
          }, 2500);
        });
      });

/* 3. Solution */

      amount >= 100 ? await message.delete() /* You can only bulk delete 100 messages */ : amount++;

      await message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).then((_message) => {
        message.channel.send(`Bot cleared \`${_message.size}\` messages :broom:`).then((sent) => {
          setTimeout(function () {
            sent.delete();
          }, 2500);
        });
      });

/* The following code is your old code */

    } else {
      message.channel.send('enter the amount of messages that you would like to clear').then((sent) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
          sent.delete();
        }, 2500);
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'help clear') {
      const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('#00B2B2').setTitle('**Clear Help**');
      newEmbed
        .setDescription('This command clears messages for example `.clear 5` or `.c 5`.')
        .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp();
      message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
  }
});
```